# Django with mod_wsgi doesn't work with Postgis

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, postgis, selinux

I am trying to make my **django** project work with httpd using **mod_wsgi**. But I keep getting a "500 Internal Server Error". I am using a **PostgreSQL Postgis** database. My OS is Fedora 20.

What is really weird is that :

- The project works just fine when I use Django development Server instead of httpd.
- It also works fine when I use *something other than Postgis*, i.e. when I replace the followig line in the file *settings.py* :

  `'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',`

  by any other database (mysql, sqlite3..), such as :

  `'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',`

Here is my httpd configuration file for the django project (let's say it is called `testproject`) (I put this file in `/etc/httpd/conf.d`):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName testproject.com

DocumentRoot /var/www/testproject

WSGIProcessGroup testproject
WSGIDaemonProcess testproject threads=4

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/testproject/django.wsgi

Alias /static/ "/var/www/testproject/static/"
<Location "/media">
    SetHandler None
</Location>
<LocationMatch "\.(jpg|gif|png|js|css)$">
    SetHandler None
</LocationMatch>
<Directory /var/www/testproject>
    WSGIProcessGroup testproject
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The part of the project settings (`settings.py`) that is apparently generating the error:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'db_name',                      
        'USER': 'db_user',                      
        'PASSWORD': '',                  
        'HOST': '',                      
        'PORT': '',                     
    }
}
```

When I try to access the URL `testproject.com`, I get a "500 Internal Server Error", and the httpd error log is the following:

```
[Mon May 12 14:34:35.462830 2014] [:info] [pid 20762] [remote 127.0.0.1:33403] mod_wsgi (pid=20762, process='testproject', application=''): Loading WSGI script '/var/www/testproject/django.wsgi'.
[Mon May 12 14:34:35.799954 2014] [core:error] [pid 20537] [client 127.0.0.1:49565] End of script output before headers: django.wsgi
[Mon May 12 14:34:35.884215 2014] [core:notice] [pid 20530] AH00052: child pid 20762 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Mon May 12 14:34:35.884237 2014] [:info] [pid 20530] mod_wsgi (pid=20762): Process 'testproject' has died, restarting.
[Mon May 12 14:34:35.884240 2014] [:info] [pid 20530] mod_wsgi (pid=20762): Process 'testproject' terminated by signal 11
[Mon May 12 14:34:35.884728 2014] [:info] [pid 20978] mod_wsgi (pid=20978): Starting process 'testproject' with uid=48, gid=48 and threads=4.
[Mon May 12 14:34:35.884981 2014] [:info] [pid 20978] mod_wsgi (pid=20978): Initializing Python.
[Mon May 12 14:34:35.892051 2014] [:info] [pid 20978] mod_wsgi (pid=20978): Attach interpreter ''
```

I insist on the fact that this error is only happening using `django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis`, but it's working fine using any of the `django.db.backends.*`.

Any help or idea would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is preferred that you post the solution you found as an Answer and then accept it

Comment: Okay, I am not allowed to do it right now (I have less than 10 reputation, so I have to wait 8 hours to answer my own post) but I'll do it as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found where the problem was. It was coming from **SELinux policy** that was apparently denying the permission for httpd to access the page.

I had in my `/var/log/httpd/error_log` the following line:

```
[Mon May 12 14:04:34.876392 2014] [core:notice] [pid 20070] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
```

Then I ran the two following command lines:

```
sudo grep httpd /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M mypol
sudo semodule -i mypol.pp
```

And it worked again.